# React serialize Component to send from server

Tags: javascript, serialization, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a site which contains some kind of blog. I'd like to write my individual blog posts as React components, so that they can contain other components.

Blog posts look like the following and are within separat files.

```
export default {
  name: 'test',
  title: 'Test',
  description: 'Description todo …',
  featureUrl: '/img/articles/test.jpg',
  component: class extends React.Component{
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Here goes the test article …</p>
          <p>Some more …</p>
          <p>Some more …</p>
          <p>Some more …</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
};
```

The app supports server rendering. On the server the articles are loaded into a Flux store and may be rendered depending on a route: E.g. a blog list or a specific blog post itself.

Then I want to send the state of the Flux store to the client, which causes the object to being serialized. Since functions can't be serialized the component is lost. On the client I'd like to pick up the state from the server. But I'm missing the component then.

What is a good strategy to deal with this?

I've seen [Yahoo has a library](https://github.com/yahoo/serialize-javascript) to serialize also functions, but this seems somewhat hacky to me.

What I'm doing currently, is to import all articles in the component that should render an article and render a specific based on the current article that is available in the Flux state.

```
import * as articles from 'articles';
(...)
let component = articles[articleName].component;
```

This works, but isn't actually what I want. I'd like the component to be available through the state from the store. Another option would be to reinitialize the store on the client, but then the whole point of sending the state from the server to the client is pointless.

Is there a better way to handle this?

I'm using Redux as a Flux library.

Comment: It seems like it would be a lot easier to have the post be HTML and then pre-process the HTML to see if it references any other components using `data-` attributes or something. This is also a perfect use-case for a webcomponent.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with just wanting to serialize the store.

The basic idea with server rendering is that when a request comes in to your server you gather the necessary data (in your case a blog post), create a Redux store with it, then render the entire app component tree to a string server side pre-populated with the correct state.

Here's a rough example for a Node.js server rendering method using Redux 1.0.0 syntax and ES6:

```
const initialState = {
  post: getBlogPostById(id); // or however you get your data
};

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

const stateString = JSON.stringify(initialState);

const appString = React.renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {() => <App/>}
  </Provider>
);
```

Now you have both your entire app rendered to a string displaying the correct state as `appString`, and the same data stringified too as `stateString`, so now you just need to render them into your template ready for sending to the client. Using Handlebars syntax something like,

```
<body>
  <div id="app">{{{appString}}}</div>
  <script>window.INITIAL_STATE = {{{stateString}}}</script>
  <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

In this example `app.js` is your concatenated JS code that contains the code necessary to grab that `stateString` data, re-create the same Redux store with it and then render the same component tree. React is smart enough to efficiently "re-hydrate" the existing DOM we created server side when it initialises the same component tree on the client. So your client JS might look something like,

```
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer, window.INITIAL_STATE);

React.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {() => <App/>}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

---

As an aside, the way you have your component exported as a property of a native object together with some metadata doesn't look very idiomatic. Typically with React there's a "one component per file" convention, and then you can store your metadata elsewhere in a dedicated JSON file somewhere. It might help with the architecture of your app to separate your UI component definitions from your data structure, but YMMV of course ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Actually i got the idea from [Percolate Studio](https://github.com/percolatestudio/percolatestudio.com/blob/master/app/components/jobs/designIntern.jsx#L13). I also like the one component per file convention, but for this it felt good to me.

Regarding serialization: Actually I have the de-/rehydrating already working. Except for the component. The serialized version of the store includes all the data except for the component, since that is a function and functions can't be serialized. They're just stripped away from the object …

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by serializing the components. As far as I understand it the components don't need to be serialized at all ... only the state needs to be serialized since the components are re-created on the client based on that state.